# What is the difference between _spawnl and Createprocess(...) API in windows programming?

Tags: windows, winapi

What is the difference between **_spawnl(...)** and **Createprocess(...)** API in windows programming?

In what way these API's differ in creating process behavior.

Comment: CreateProcess is the fifty horsepower chain-saw.  _spawnl() is the butter knife.  It's like the Pink Floyd song, careful with that axe Eugene.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`CreateProcess` is the native API for creating processes.

`spawnl` is part of the C runtime, with POSIX-like semantics. It supports only a small subset of the functionality (supplying command line arguments) and is implemented as a wrapper around `CreateProcess`. In the mean time, `spawnl` has been deprecated in favour of `_spawnl`.

The natural mode of operation for `CreateProcess` is comparable to the `P_NOWAIT` mode of `spawnl`, but with additional features (environment, standard handles security info, ...).

Note that the `P_OVERLAY` mode in `spawnl` is not something that is directly supported under Windows at all (there is no Unix-like `fork`+`execve` idiom, processes are created anew, not forked). This functionality is thus implemented by spawning a new process and terminating the original one, rather than by replacing the process.

Comment: Also note that _spawnl does not always properly construct the command line from the arguments.  If your arguments contain special characters, it is probably preferable to use CreateProcess.